# Server memory usage

Tags: сервер, memory, centos6

Всем добрый день! Вопрос в следующем, есть vps сервер на котором всего один рабочий сайт. На сайте все время работает крон, так как надо получать определенные данные по API и класть их в кеш. Раз или два раза в неделю кончается память на сервере и все умирает.. 
Решил поставить на сервер htop и посмотреть что там вообще происходит.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
И получается что из 4гб оперативки 3гб все время занято какой-то фигней для Cpanel - кто может подсказать что вообще это за процессы такие, откуда они берутся и зачем они нужны. И какой выход есть из этой ситуации, просто добавить оперативки или надо что бы сервер настраивал специалист?

Всем заранее спасибо!

Comment: это потоки одного процесса, в сумме они 5.5% по памяти съедают. Надо дебажить крон таски, логировать потребление памяти и выяснить где утечка.

Comment: Одинаковое количество памяти у похожих записей - верный признак того, что вы смотрите потоки, а не процессы. Отключите вывод потоков в настройках htop, чтобы не запутываться. А судя по верхним строчкам, с памятью в данный момент всё в порядке, занят всего гигабайт, так что настраивайте мониторинг (atop например)

Comment: Спасибо, попробую еще немного сам разобраться. Просто не понятно тогда отчего же он валится время от времени..